# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type

Tags: swift

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Void' (aka '()') and 'String?'

I am trying Swift for the first time.

I am getting error in this code:

```
    let username = usernameTextfeild.text;
    let password = passwordTextfeild.text;

   let usernameStored =  UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "userName");
   let passwordStored =  UserDefaults.standard.set(password, forKey: "password");

    if(usernameStored == username)
```

Here error is in == operator. I tried some answers from stack but don't know what to use.

Comment: usernameStored is not a string

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set` and its overloaded methods also return void.

Comment: So I have to write it in string thn only it will work?

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "userName");` doesn't return anything (hence the Void), so you're just storing the void.

Comment: thx you  @kbunarjo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to compare the result of storing the username which is `Void` to the username value, which is a `String`. You cannot compare `Void` to `String`.

You must first get the value from `UserDefaults` like this:

```
let storedValue = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userName")
```

Comment: OP is comparing `Void` and `String` (he's not comparing `usernameStored` and `passwordStored`, but rather `usernameStored` and `username`)